# Converting stateful React component to stateless functional component: How to implement "componentDidMount" kind of functionality?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, event-handling, window-load

I have written a small stateful React component. When this component loads, in `componentDidMount` method I am making use of Kendo UI to show the content of the component in a popup window.

Here's my code:

```
export class ErrorDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.errorPopupWindow = null;
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeComponent);
    this.handleWindowKeyDown = this.handleWindowKeyDown.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonCloseWindowOnClick = this.handleButtonCloseWindowOnClick.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonShowDetailsOnClick = this.handleButtonShowDetailsOnClick.bind(this);
    $('#ErrorInformationForm-CloseWindow').focus();
  }

  render() {
    const errorInformation = this.props.errorInformation;
    const baseException = errorInformation.baseException;
    const showExceptionMessage = (typeof baseException !== 'undefined' && typeof baseException === 'object' && baseException !== null
          && typeof baseException.message !== 'undefined' && typeof baseException.message === 'string' && baseException.message !== null
          && baseException.message !== '') ? true : false;
    const baseExceptionMessage = showExceptionMessage ? baseException.message : '';
    const exceptionMessageCss = showExceptionMessage ? 'k-textbox ce-width-100-pct ce-margin-top-5' : 'ce-invisible';
    return(
      <div id="Error-Dialog-Popup" onKeyDown={this.handleWindowKeyDown}>
        <div className="ce-window-body">
          {errorInformation.message}
          <code>
            <textarea readOnly={true} className={exceptionMessageCss} rows="3" defaultValue={baseExceptionMessage} />
          </code>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const errorInformation = this.props.errorInformation;
    const modalWindowTitle = '<span class="ce-width-100-pct ce-app-color-red"><i class="fa ce-fs-1-2-5x fa-times-circle"></i> ' + errorInformation.heading + '</span>';
    $('#Error-Dialog-Popup').kendoWindow({
      actions: [],
      width: 500,
      height: 130,
      visible: true,
      modal: true,
      title: modalWindowTitle,
      resizable: false
    });
    this.resizeComponent();
  }

  resizeComponent() {
  }

  closeWindowIfPossible(evt) {
  }

  handleWindowKeyDown(evt) {
  }

  handleButtonShowDetailsOnClick(evt) {
  }

  handleButtonCloseWindowOnClick(evt) {
  }
}
```

Given that this component doesn't need to maintain any state, I am trying to convert this component into a stateless functional component.

The place where I am struggling is **how to implement componentDidMount functionality**? Here's the code I have written so far:

```
export const ErrorDialog = (props, context) => {
  const errorInformation = props.errorInformation;
  const baseException = errorInformation.baseException;
  const showExceptionMessage = (typeof baseException !== 'undefined' && typeof baseException === 'object' && baseException !== null
        && typeof baseException.message !== 'undefined' && typeof baseException.message === 'string' && baseException.message !== null
        && baseException.message !== '') ? true : false;
  const baseExceptionMessage = showExceptionMessage ? baseException.message : '';
  const exceptionMessageCss = showExceptionMessage ? 'k-textbox ce-width-100-pct ce-margin-top-5' : 'ce-invisible';

  const resizeComponent = () => {
  }

  const closeWindowIfPossible = (evt) => {
  }

  const handleWindowKeyDown = (evt) => {
  }

  const handleButtonShowDetailsOnClick = (evt) => {
  }

  const handleButtonCloseWindowOnClick = (evt) => {
  }

  const handleComponentOnLoad = (evt) => {
    console.log('comes in onLoad');
    const errorInformation = props.errorInformation;
    const modalWindowTitle = '<span class="ce-width-100-pct ce-app-color-red"><i class="fa ce-fs-1-2-5x fa-times-circle"></i> ' + errorInformation.heading + '</span>';
    $('#Error-Dialog-Popup').kendoWindow({
      actions: [],
      width: 500,
      height: 130,
      visible: true,
      modal: true,
      title: modalWindowTitle,
      resizable: false
    });
    resizeComponent();
  }

  return(
    <div id="Error-Dialog-Popup" onLoad={handleComponentOnLoad} onKeyDown={handleWindowKeyDown}>
      <div className="ce-window-body">
        {errorInformation.message}
        <code>
          <textarea readOnly={true} className={exceptionMessageCss} rows="3" defaultValue={baseExceptionMessage} />
        </code>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

At first, I thought I could implement `componentDidMount` kind of functionality in `onLoad` event handler of the div but when I tried doing it I noticed that the event is not fired at all (I then read the documentation and found out that I can't really  use this event :)).

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to implement `componentDidMount` kind of functionality in stateless functional components? Essentially what I need to do is do something with the component when it is loaded in DOM.
- Is what I am trying to do is a valid scenario in case of a stateless functional component or should I just stick with standard component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Functional stateless components do not have lifecycle methods. You should stick with standard component in this case.**

---

From React's [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions):

> These components must not retain internal state, do not have backing instances, and do not have the component lifecycle methods.

Comment: Thanks @leo. I am hoping there's some secret sauce to achieve what I am trying to accomplish :).

Comment: hm, why are you so keen on using stateless component? maybe we can work towards a solution

Comment: No particular reason. I really liked the clean implementation of stateless component + I don't have to remember `this` binding.

Comment: yes, stateless components are really clean and +1 for trying to use them, but I'm afraid that there is no way - they're just a function.

Comment: Thanks Leo. Let's keep this question open for some time and see if the community has some other thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

In React 16.8, you can now use [State Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) for functional components. For `componentDidMount`, it's recommended to use [Effect Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  }, [count]); // Only re-run the effect if count changes)

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/rjruizes/pen/yLMZPvR

If you want the Effect Hook to only run after mount, use an empty array as the condition:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

What they said (above), but also consider making a stateful component container and passing props/args to subcomponents which are stateless.